# What is the best path to learn Category theory and Type theory?

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, type-theory

> I have little background in Programming in functional languages and wanted to learn type theory. I started with taking Homotopy type theory class Online videos of [Robert Harper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/courses/hott/). I thought rather than Going Slow I could just start there as this class was  also meant for the people with no background in type theory.

I'm computer programmer and too much math drains my brain.

The thing I found very interesting was Category theory. I never wanted to learn that but looks i found that so elegant. 
Now i want to go Slow starting for base of leaning category theory and Type theory. I learn things in fragments and also understood many concepts. But Not too clear.

I know this question have been answered before in respect to category theory. But kindly suggest me, from the perspective of a computer programmer, the starting point of both these Theories and Books / articles / Blogs to start as there are too many of them present. So that I could converge understanding from both fields perspective.

Thank you.

Comment: Learning category theory will be tough if you don’t have a reasonable background in abstract algebra. Perhaps one can compensate this with a good understanding of functional programming? I would start off by learning the basics of [Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) (if you haven’t done this before) and learn about fundamental algebraic structures like monoids, rings and groups. Once you are used to these concepts, moving on to category theory will be much less tedious. (Also, I woudn’t focus too much on the set-theoretic aspects of algebra because that could lead you astray.)

Comment: I have a sufficient knowledge of Haskell.After taking Hott course even tried Idris & Agda also. But lacks any comfortable understanding of Abstract algebra.

Comment: Have you already had a look at the [catsters](https://www.youtube.com/user/TheCatsters) videos on category theory?

Comment: Any other Better way or should i commit to the same ?

Comment: I wouldn’t know. I don’t know Awodey.

Comment: I actually started typing a fairly long answer but then realized there's http://mathoverflow.net/questions/903/resources-for-learning-practical-category-theory/ and I was basically duplicating that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best introduction to category theory I know for non-mathematics students is Steve Awodey's *Category Theory*. Developed as an introduction to category theory for philosophy of mathematics students, the author has also used the original lecture notes to teach computer science majors as well. The book is careful,clear, has many examples and exercises and doesn't pour on too much hardcore mathematics. I consider it one of the best books out there for undergraduates on the subject and I think you might find it just what you're looking for.

I used to recommend Adowey all the time for undergraduates. But for **mathematics** students,to be honest, I'd prefer Harold Simmons' wonderful *Introduction to Category Theory*. It's beautifully written and pitched at about the same level as Awodey, but it's much more mathematical and contains far more algebra and topology then you might feel comfortable with. You might want to take a look at it, but be warned-it's really pitched at mathematics students.

Comment: Yeah seen that book and Robert harper endorsed it too. So Thinking of Starting Oregon summer school Videos of Steve Awodey with this. I had seen His first video Lecture but unable to go further during my first half of study of Hott. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You may find [Categories for Types](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521457017) more suitable than Awodey or Simmons (perhaps to be followed by reading Awodey).